# how to set background color of specific recyclerview card (via method) when clicked

Tags: android, android-view, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

i am trying to set the background of the card i have clicked on in my recycle view (to reflect the connection status of bluetooth device).
i have got all the steps needed for the itemclick (adapter, set onitemclickloistener, etc)
but cannot find a way to set the background? (i am only able to find the OBJECT of the card ive clicked not the VIEW to set it's background programatically)

my listener set from main activity:

```
//task to carry out when clicking a card item
        recycAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new CardAdapterDevice.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(int position) {

                //create pop up choice to connect to device
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(BluetoothActions.this);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_popup_connect_to_device);
                dialog.setTitle("Connect to Device");

                //assign dialog button etc (to call connection and set background method)

                dialog.show();
            }
        });
```

but i want to call a method when the dialog button is pushed, to complete the connection and to set the background of the card.
i have spent a couple hours now researching online and experimenting, trying to figure this out and i just cant seem to find anything that works?

can anyone suggest how to do this?

**edit:** as suggested i have included my adapter below for reference.

```
public class CardAdapterDevice extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapterDevice.CardViewHolder> {
    private static final String TAG = "CardAdapterDevice";

    private ArrayList<DeviceCard> cardList;
    private OnItemClickListener clickListener;
    public CardAdapterDevice(ArrayList<DeviceCard> exampleList) {
        cardList = exampleList;
    }

    //-listens for card click in recyclerView
    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(int position);
    }

    public static class CardViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView deviceIcon;
        public TextView deviceName;
        public ImageView connect;

        public CardViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, final OnItemClickListener listener) {
            super(itemView);
            //references to views (pass values in onBindViewHolder)
            deviceIcon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_carddevice_icon);
            deviceName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.labeltext_carddevice_device_name);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (listener != null) {
                        int position = getAdapterPosition();
                        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                            listener.onItemClick(position);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CardAdapterDevice.CardViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.card_device, parent, false);
        CardViewHolder cvh = new CardViewHolder(v, clickListener);
        return cvh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CardAdapterDevice.CardViewHolder holder, int position) {
        //pass information to item currently looked at (position)
        DeviceCard currentItem = cardList.get(position); //item at position
        //get info (image (in holder) changed to image returned by ArrayList item (currentItem))
        holder.deviceIcon.setImageResource(currentItem.getImageResource());
        holder.deviceName.setText(currentItem.getDeviceName());
    }

    //-get number of items in list
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return cardList
                .size();
    }


    //-sets the desired click listener
    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
        clickListener = listener;
    }
}
```

also hoping to clarify things a little:
If i had manually created each card as a variable myself, 
i would have direct access to it and could call methods like `cardView.setBackgroundColor(etc)`
 however as they are created and added to the recyclerView autonomously, i dont have that variable and need to find a way to get the view reference from the click itself?

i have seen a lot of onBindAdapter examples, but unless i am missing something that doesnt help me get the card view at the moment of clicking it? (the adapter already has been bound at this point?)

Comment: add your xml and adapter complete code.

Comment: the complete code is a few thousand lines long so cant do that.
i'll add the adapter though.
i literally just want to know how to get the view reference for the specific card i clicked? (ie: if i had manually created each card i would have cardView.setBackgroundColor(etc), however as they are created and added to the recyclerView, i dont have that variable and need to get the reference from the click itself?